# Question on Conditional Expectation. with sum of Bernouli random variables.

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

X is a uniform random variable on $[n]=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ and for every $i\in[n]$ We define$ Y_i \sim Ber(\frac{1}{2})$ ,such that all The variables are independent(all The Y's and X). now we have to calculate the following expectations:
$$a_{1}=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}|Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1]$$
and
$$a_{2}=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}]$$
And after you calculate the expected values, **you have to explain why for large $n$ we get that $a_{1}$ is much smaller than $a_{2}$.**

The problem is that I got that $a_1>a_2$, always, like this:
$$a_{1}=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}|Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1]\stackrel{\text{adds 1 X times}}{=}\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{n+1}{2}$$
$$a_{2}=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}\vert X=k]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le k}Y_{i}]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=k)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}[Y_{i}]=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2}=\frac{1}{2n}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n+1}{4}$$
And $\frac{n+1}{2}>\frac{n+1}{4}$, always.
Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

This question was given as homework.

Comment: No part of your work makes sense without independence assumptions.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I added the assumptions.

Comment: $a_1=E(X|Y_1=Y_2=...=Y_X=1]$ and not $EX$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in $a_{1}=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}\mid Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1]\stackrel{\text{adds 1 X times}}{=}\mathbb{E}[X]$ as you are taking the conditional expectations in the wrong order.  Assuming independence:

- The event $X=x$ has probability $\frac1n$
- The joint event $(X=x) \cap (Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{x}=1)$ has probability $\frac1{n2^x}$
- so $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i\le X}Y_{i}\mid Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1\right] =\dfrac{\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \frac x{n2^x} }{\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \frac 1{n2^x}}=2-\dfrac{n}{2^n-1}$
- which is  less than $\frac{n+1}{4}$ for $n\ge 7$ and, since it is bounded above by $2$, a lot less for large $n$.

As an illustration when $n=2$, you have

- $\mathbb P(X=1, Y_1=1)=\frac14$
- $\mathbb P(X=2, Y_1=Y_2=1)=\frac18$
- so $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i\le X}Y_{i}\mid Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1\right] = \frac{1\times \frac14+2\times\frac18}{\frac14+\frac18}=\frac43$

which is not your $\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac32$

Comment: first of all, thank you,
Can you explain what "you are taking the conditional expectations in the wrong order" means? because I thought that if I know all the terms in the sum are one I can say that the sum is X.
Second of all, how did you calculate the expected value at the end? I get why the probability of the joint events is what you've written down, but don't understand the step from the expectation to the division of the sums

Comment: @Volxxe I have given an example for $n=2$ which may help

Comment: but why is this true?
$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i\le X}Y_{i}\mid Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1\right] = \frac{1\times \frac14+2\times\frac18}{\frac14+\frac18}=\frac43$

Comment: The way I've seen to calculate the expectation is this one: $$\mathbb{E}[X|A]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\mathbb{P}(X=k|A)$$ where $A$ is an event.
And this one:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum\mathbb{E}[X|A]\mathbb{P}(A)$$

Comment: @Volxxe - try it with coin flips: $\frac14$ of the time you get $X=1$ and $Y_1$, and $\frac18$ of the time you get $X=2$ and $Y_1=1$ and $Y_2=1$; the other $\frac 58$ of the time you get something else which you ignore because you do not meet the condition $Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1$.  So given that the condition is met, having seen $X=1$ is twice as likely as having seen $X=2$ and this pushes down the  conditional expectation.

Comment: @Volxxe In your $\mathbb{E}[X\mid A]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\mathbb{P}(X=k\mid A)$, you need to find $\mathbb{P}(X=k\mid A)$.  Your original calculations used $\frac1n$, but this was  $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$ not $\mathbb{P}(X=k\mid A)$.

Comment: But $X$ in our case is $\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}$ so you have to calculate:
$\sum_{x=1}^{n}x\cdot\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i\le X}Y_{i}=x|Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1)$
And then I said that this means that $X$ needs to be $x$ so I need to calculate that probability, I guess that's my mistake but I don't get why it's wrong

Comment: @Volxxe That conditional probability is in effect $\mathbb{P}(X=x\mid Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1)$ $=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=x \cap Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{x}=1)}{\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X=x \cap Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{x}=1)}$ and is not equal to the unconditional $P(X=x)$.  Conditioning on $Y_{1}=Y_{2}=\dots=Y_{X}=1$, which is decreasingly likely as $X$ increases, makes it more probable that $X$ is a small number and so reduces the conditional expectation

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much